# cake php Auth login not working online but working locally

Tags: cakephp

i am using cakephp Auth login it is not working online but on localhost it is working fine.

```
class AppController extends Controller {
    public $components=array(
    'Auth'=>array(
        'authenticate'=>array(
            'Form'=>array(
                'userModel'=>'User',
                'fields'=>array(
                    'username'=>'uid',
                    'password'=>'password',
                    ),
                )
            ),
            'loginAction' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'),
            'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'dashboard'),
            'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'),
            'authError' => 'You don\'t have access here.',
            ),
    'Session'
    );
```

this login() method in UsersController this is working fine at localhost what changes should be done when we are uploading any file on server in cakephp

```
public function login(){
    $this->layout='login';
    if($this->request->is('Post'))
    {
        if($this->Auth->login())
        {
            $user=$this->Auth->user();
            if($user['status']!=0 || $user['role']=='1')
            {
                if($user['role'])
                {
                    $role="Admin";
                    $this->Session->write('admin',$user['uid']);
                }
                else
                {
                    $role="User";
                    $this->Session->write('user',$user['uid']);
                }
                $this->Session->write('rolename',$role);
                $this->Session->write('uid',$user['uid']);
                $log['Log']['loginType']=$this->request->data['User']['loginType'];
                $log['Log']['userId']=$user['id'];
                $log['Log']['latitude']='0';//$data['User']['latitude'];
                $log['Log']['longitude']='0';//$data['User']['longitude'];
                $this->Log->save($log);
                $this->Flash->set(_('Sucessfully login'));
                $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'dashboard'));
            }
            else
            {
                $this->Flash->set('You have no access to login...');
            }
        }
       else
       $this->Flash->set('Invalid Credentials');
    }
}
```

Comment: Add your `login` action code, also tell us what error are you getting while trying to login. So that i can help you.

Comment: @MaheshSinghChouhan i have updated my question plz check

Comment: what message are you getting with `$this->Flash` while trying to login on server?